# Passing parameters to a Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I need pass a collection (or array) of parameters to my Blazor component. The parameters passing are Blazor components. The collection of parameters must be passed as a nested tag. It is necessary to be able to call the rendering of each passed parameter-component separately.

That is, I want something like this:

```html
<MyComponent>
  <ParameterCollection>
    <MyParameterComponent1>Caption1</MyParameterComponent1>
    <MyParameterComponent2>Caption2</MyParameterComponent2>
    <MyParameterComponent3>Caption3</MyParameterComponent3>
  </ParameterCollection>
</MyComponent>
```

MyComponent code:

```cs
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment[] ParameterCollection {get; set;} //Runtime error
}
```

That I want to get is apparently  implemented here [commercial Blazor component](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/grid/overview) (select the VIEW SOURCE tab).
The GridColumns parameter is passed a collection of GridColumn components. More precisely, as I think, it is a collection of their corresponding RenderFragments.
The question is how is it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn it around: the DatagGridColumnCollection component inserts itself as a CascadingValue and the DatagGridColumn components just call an Add method.

#### ColumnCollection

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
  @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code
{ 
    public void Add(DataGridColumn colum) { ... }
}
```

#### DataGridColumn

```
@code {
  [CascadingParameter]
  private ColumnCollection Parent { get; set; }
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    if (Parent != null)  Parent.Add(this);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I already tried to go the way you mentioned (component registers itself with parent collection) but ...
How to invoke rendering of DataGridColumn instances with parameters assigned to them.

Comment: Well, I imagine a Column has a Header template and a Cell template (RenderFragments). So a foreach() loop ought to work.

Comment: Hmm ... Yes, you're absolutely right. For this purpose, I will create a TemplateHolder component.
I wonder why the creators of the framework did not provide for the simply possibility of rendering a component from an instance of a descendant of ComponentBase.

Comment: I think they did. Not sure what you want really, but it's all very doable. Making a DataGrid or TabControl is easier then in any other framework I know.

Answer (score 7):

Blazor cannot get a collection of render fragment as parameters. Here are two different approaches you can pass dynamic components count as a parameter

1. If you want just to pass multiple components but it's ok they to be rendered at the same order as you passing them:

```html
<MyComponent>
    <ParameterCollection>
        <MyParameterComponent1>Caption1</MyParameterComponent1>
        <MyParameterComponent2>Caption2</MyParameterComponent2>
        <MyParameterComponent3>Caption3</MyParameterComponent3>
    </ParameterCollection>
</MyComponent>
```

```cs
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ParameterCollection {get; set;} 
}
```

and you can just render them placing `@ParameterCollection` anywhere in your `.razor` file.

Here is a working example of this approach: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QaFEadlQ52kWHVkX13

2. When you want to have both dynamic components count and you want to have control over where they are placed.

In this approach you are using the component only to pass some metadata - similar to @Henk Holterman suggestion:

```html
<MyComponent>
    <ParameterCollection>
        <MyParameterComponent1>Caption1</MyParameterComponent1>
        <MyParameterComponent2>Caption2</MyParameterComponent2>
        <MyParameterComponent3>Caption3</MyParameterComponent3>
    </ParameterCollection>
</MyComponent>
```

```cs
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ParameterCollection {get; set;} 
}
```

in this way, you can just put the @ParameterCollection at the start of your `.razor` file wrapped in CascadingValue of the Parent component. This will trigger the rendering for all the child components.

In the init of each of the components you will need to trigger populating metadata to the parent:

```cs
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private MyComponent Parent { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent != null)  Parent.AddChild(this);    
    }
}
```

After receiving the metadata, you just need to trigger rendering again and use this data in

Here is a working example: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wuPOOxvd06vFcWFG21

Comment: Thanks.
1 point is not my case. I looked at the code at the link you mentioned.
In the Parent component, you render a single parameter of the Child component, but how to render the entire Child component with its associated parameters?

Comment: I found this article which shows how to render component from its instance: https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/render-razor-component-instance-blazor. Although I'm not sure why you would want to do that.